# Laravel AJAX 404 for route

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a Laravel 5.3 solution. I try to call a POST route via AJAX from one of my views to update a set of categories but I get a 404 error everytime I call the route.

Interesting fact: During development I was able to call the route with the JS-code shown below successfully - but since I did some updates to the controller code itself it throws a 404 but no exception.

Here is my controller action:

```
public function updateTree( Request $request )
{
    $data = $request->json()->all();

    $result = BlogCategory::rebuildTree($data, false);

    if($result > 0) {
        return Response::HTTP_OK;
    }
    return Response::HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED;
}
```

And here the JS AJAX call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

var updateTree = function (e) {
    var list = e.length ? e : $(e.target), output = list.data('output');

    console.log(JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));

    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ action('BlogCategoryController@updateTree') }}',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize'))
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nestable2').nestable({
        group: 1
    }).on('change', updateTree);
});
```

The controller route is bound like that in web.php

```
Route::post( '/service/blog/categories/updatetree', 'BlogCategoryController@updateTree' );
```

As you might see, I am using the Laravel NestedSet module from LazyChaser here (https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset).

Any input is much appreciated.

Cheers,
Jules

Comment: Do you have any middleware set for this controller?

Comment: @matiit nope, just a middleware on the route group for security checks: Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'role:user|admin']], function () {...} CSRF tokens are also set up

Comment: do you get 404 when you try to make an identical request using for example PostMan?

Comment: I just tried it @matiit and postman gives me a 304 which means the route is called correctly.

Comment: No sorry @matiit if I add the payload (the JSON) to the request it gives me a 404 as well

Comment: Try this

`Route::post( '/service/blog/categories/updatetree', ['uses'=>'BlogCategoryController@updateTree','as'=>'update.tree'] );`

And call ajax

`$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('update.tree') }}",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize'))
});`

Comment: @Sovary yes I tried that already, but also named routes does not change the behaviour. Through debugging it seems that the rebuildTree method might throw the 404 even though I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

you having opening and closing quotes problem in your ajax url, use like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ action("BlogCategoryController@updateTree") }}',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize'))
});
```

Comment: Hi Raushan, I double checked that, but this does not cause the problem. Still getting 404 when calling the route. Thank you for your input - any more ideas probably?

Comment: whay not you giving the complete url in your ajax url value as `url:'/service/blog/categories/updatetree'`

Comment: Hey Raushan, I tried to replace my action() call with a static url but still the same issue. Action() will actually print the entire url including protocol and hostname to the view when compiled. The code above just shows my blade-view.